# Knowing the family with Socket Descriptor

Tags: c, ipv6

I have the socket descriptor which is the return value of socket API. How can I use only this to know the family?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call `getsockname`, but only after the socket is bound.

Answer (score 1):

*(Windows-specific):* 
you can get **SO_PROTOCOL_INFO** socket option.

If successful, it would give you [WSAPROTOCOL_INFO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms741675%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) structure with `iAddressFamily` member.